# Update No Rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, error-handling, return

I have a simple SQL update statement...

```
UPDATE [Table].[dbo].[Test]
SET [Field1] = @Param1
WHERE [Field2] = @Param2
```

Let's say my data set is ONLY the following information...

```
 Field 1     |     Field 2
-------------------------
 123         |     abc
 456         |     def
 789         |     ghi
```

My issue is as this... What if a user wants to update 'Field1' for 'def' to '444', but, oh no! They accidentally key 'dew' for 'Param2'. So this is our param set...

- Param1: 444
- Param2: dew

According to my testing I am getting a 'Command(s) completed successfully', because technically it did, but there is no way for my user to know that they didn't actually update anything. Is there an error code, return code, something that could flag me to send a message to my user letting them know the operation was a success, but it didn't update anything because the record didn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@@RowCount](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) is what you are looking for.